# Insert node after specific node using batch

Tags: batch-file

When i write this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=New value

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (2.xml) do (

   set "line=%%a"
   set "newLine=!line:SelfBillingIndicator>=!"
   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      set "newLine=!line!"
      echo !newLine!
      set "newLine=<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>"
   ) 
   @echo !newLine!
)) > 3.xml
```

i have a problem on my code, i need  `"newLine=<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>"` appears on SelfBillingIndicator, but only in a specific node. i have lot off nodes in xml who have got SelfBillingIndicator, my program replace all but i only need to replace inside `<Invoice>` node. look the example:

```
<Document>
<SelfBillingIndicator>0</SelfBillingIndicator>
<Document>
<Invoice>
<InvoiceNo>F 2013A/321</InvoiceNo>
<SelfBillingIndicator>0</SelfBillingIndicator>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Can you guarantee file is always formatted that way? [tag:xml] parsing in [tag:batch] is tricky... There are some command line utilities better suited for such function.

Comment: that lines i used in batch work correct for me in my xml file, but it replace every <SelfBillingIndicator> </SelfBillingIndicator>, inside and outside my <Invoice>. I only need to replace inside <Invoice>, idont wonderstand what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Added variable `inside_Invoice` which will turn `1` when finds `<Invoice>` and `0` when finds `</Invoice>`.

Then, modifying variable is only allowed when `inside_Invoice==1`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=New value
SET inside_Invoice=0

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (2.xml) do (

   set "line=%%a"
   IF "%%a"=="<Invoice>" SET inside_Invoice=1
   IF "%%a"=="</Invoice>" SET inside_Invoice=0
   SET "newLine=%%a"
   IF !inside_Invoice!==1 set "newLine=!line:SelfBillingIndicator>=!"
   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
       set "newLine=!line!"
       echo !newLine!
       set "newLine=<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>"
   )
   @echo !newLine!
)) > 3.xml
```

EDIT: Sometimes, we'd better rewrite everything...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET inside_Invoice=0
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (2.xml) do (
    ECHO.%%a
    IF "%%a"=="<Invoice>" (
        SET inside_Invoice=1
    ) ELSE IF "%%a"=="</Invoice>" (
        SET inside_Invoice=0
    ) ELSE IF !inside_Invoice!==1 (
        ECHO "%%a"|FIND "<SelfBillingIndicator>">NUL&&ECHO ^<SourceID^>Admin^</SourceID^>
    )
))>3.xml
```

EDIT: As I told you, "XML parsing in batch is tricky"!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET inside_Invoice=0
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (2.xml) do (
    ECHO.%%a
    ECHO "%%a"|FIND "<Invoice>">NUL&&SET inside_Invoice=1
    ECHO "%%a"|FIND "</Invoice>">NUL&&SET inside_Invoice=0
    IF !inside_Invoice!==1 ECHO "%%a"|FIND "<SelfBillingIndicator>">NUL&&ECHO ^<SourceID^>Admin^</SourceID^>
))>3.xml
```

Note (this) batch checks full line at once. XML should be parsed node by node.

And you can have multiple nodes in same line or one single node can use several lines.

If you need to handle arbitrary XML data, I suggest you to consider a [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript)+[msxml](/questions/tagged/msxml) solution.

Comment: Corrected: Forgot to update `newLine` when `inside_Invoice=0`.

Comment: With your sample, my testings returned pretended results... (Deve ser contra a política do SO não falar em inglês!)

Comment: yahh you are correct in the example it works but on my project it not works i thing is because <Invoice></Invoice> is inside off other tags, i forgot to mension that. how can i reajust your code?

Comment: Now i only have a problem, inside node <Invoice></Invoice> i need to delete in all <Invoice></Invoice> this <Currency>
     <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
    </Currency>, with this last code you had made how can i edit it to not echo but delete?

Comment: Instead of `ECHO.%%a` use `ECHO "%%a"|FIND "<CurrencyCode>EUR">NUL||ECHO.%%a`. This will try find `CurrencyCode` in line and if fail prints line.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set anotherVariable=New value

set inInvoice=false

(for /F "delims=" %%a in (2.xml) do (

   set "line=%%a"
   set "newLine=!line:SelfBillingIndicator>=!"
   if "!newLine!" neq "!line!" (
      if "!inInvoice!" equ "true" (
         set "newLine=!line!"
         echo !newLine!
         set "newLine=<SourceID>Admin</SourceID>"
      )
   ) else if "!line!" equ "<Invoice>" (
      set inInvoice=true
   ) else if "!line!" equ "</Invoice>" (
      set inInvoice=false
   )
   @echo !newLine!
)) > 3.xml
```

Comment: hi Aacini thanks for the help, but seems to do the samething, the code delete all my <SelfBillingIndicator></SelfBillingIndicator> in all my code including in <Invoide></Invoide>